# Defining new data types in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, algebraic-data-types

I first need to mention that I'm quite new to Scheme and as such, the following question might not make too much sense.

At school, we've defined **algebraic data types**, that typically had a nullary constructor and some internal/external ones as well.

In this particular case, I'm interested in making a `BTree` binary tree type (perhaps balanced, in a future iteration) and I'd like something like [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor) which is how Haskell treats constructors. I've previously seen how to implement trees in Scheme, [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Binary_tree_%28Scheme%29) for instance, but this is **not** what I want.

I don't want is to just make a wrapper around lists. I simply want to write something like:

```
nil: -> BTree
node: BTree x T x BTree -> BTree
```

and then have it **know** what I mean by:

```
flattenTree: BTree -> List
```

and then, I would define it to be (assuming `left`, `right`, `key` are defined):

```
(define flattenTree
  (lambda (t)
    (node (flattenTree (left t))
          (key t)
          (flattenTree (right t)))))
```

Also, I welcome suggestions for properly indenting my Scheme code... (and be kindly modded up)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The canonical way to represent binary trees (and most other data structures) in Scheme is by [using lists](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_idx_2150). Some implementations of Scheme provide a facility to define new data types as in the style of C structs. In [MzScheme](http://racket-lang.org/) (now Racket), a new binary tree data type could be defined as:

```
(define-struct btree (key left right))
```

The environment will automatically create constructor, accessor and mutator procedures for the new struct.

```
> (define tree (make-btree 1 null null))
> (btree-key tree)
=> 10
> (set-btree-key! tree 10)
```

On top of this infrastructure, you can define additional procedures that manipulate the btree :

```
(define (btree-insert! t key)
  (if (< key (btree-key t))
      (if (null? (btree-left t))
          (set-btree-left! t (make-btree key null null))
          (btree-insert (btree-left t) key))
      (if (null? (btree-right t))
          (set-btree-right! t (make-btree key null null))
          (btree-insert (btree-right t) key))))

(define (btree-flatten t)
  (define (flatten t result)
    (if (not (null? t))
        (begin
          (append result (append (flatten (btree-left t) ()) 
                                 (list (btree-key t)))
                  (flatten (btree-right t) ())))
        t))
  (flatten t ()))

;; test

> (define tree (make-btree 10 null null))
> (btree-insert! tree 12)
> (btree-insert! tree 9)
> (btree-insert! tree 8)
> (btree-insert! tree 15)
> (btree-flatten tree)
=> (8 9 10 12 15)
```